# Make inside table be as wide as its contents inside an overflowing div

Tags: html, css

I have a table inside a div whose style is *table-wrapper*:

```
.table-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 800px;
}
```

As you can see I want this div to show a horizontal scroll bar so the table inside it can be as wide as it should. Problem is, my table still adjust itself to occupy exactly the width of the wrapper, rendering the scrollbar useless. This is the table style:

```
.elements-table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

How can I get my table to be as wide as it should?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `width:100%`, the element will try to match the width of its parent container, which in this case is `800px`.

You'll need to set a hard or `min-width` on your table to have your parent `.table-wrapper` scroll.